# zero padding in TCL

Tags: formatting, tcl, padding, zero

My tcl code looks like this:

```
set writes 1a8000028020900

binary scan [binary format H* $writes] B* bits
puts "$bits"
```

**Output:**

> 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **0 0 0 0**

If input hex value is of even length there would be no padding. If it is odd, like in the example above, zeros are getting padded.

If the number of digits formatted does not end at a byte boundary, the remaining bits of the last byte will be zeros. **How to avoid this padding**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the number of digits formatted does not end at a byte boundary, the
>   remaining bits of the last byte will be zeros. How to avoid this
>   padding?

Well, you will have to compute and tell `binary scan` the targeted number of bits. Maybe there is a more elegant way than this, but why not simply DIY?

```
% set writes 1a8000028020900
1a8000028020900
% set hexLength [string length $writes]
15
% binary scan [binary format H* $writes] B[expr {$hexLength * 4}] bits
1
% puts $bits
000110101000000000000000000000101000000000100000100100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/binary.htm) page says:

*If arg has fewer than count digits, then zeros will be used for the remaining  digits.*

The value you are supplying does not specify all 64 bits.  The `binary` command cannot guess what you want, and pads zeros on to the end of the supplied string.

Edit:

To avoid this, simply define all bits in the value to be converted:

```
set writes 01a8000028020900
```

Comment: Yes, If the number of digits formatted does not end at a byte boundary, the
remaining bits of the last byte will be zeros. How to avoid this padding?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought about padding the source string:

```
binary scan [binary format H* $writes] B* bits
puts "$bits"

binary scan [binary format H* [format "%016s" $writes]] B* bits
puts "$bits"
```

outputs

```
0001101010000000000000000000001010000000001000001001000000000000
0000000110101000000000000000000000101000000000100000100100000000
```